# Angular 2 | How to pass a model data into another model

Tags: angular

How to pass a model data into another model

For Example i want to inject the model 2 `modelUser` to model 1 `user`..

model1.ts

```
export class model1{
  constructor(private user: modelUser;){}
}
```

model2.ts

```
export class model2{
   constructor(public modelUser: string){}
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Model1.ts

```
import { Model2} from './model2'

export class Model1{
  user: Model2
}
```

Model2.ts

```
export class Model2{
   id: Number
   name: String
}
```

you can call model 2 from model 1 with something like this

```
export class Model1{
  ...
  someFunction(){
     const userDetail = {
       id: user.id
       name: user.name
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Derived classes that contain constructor functions must call super() which will execute the constructor function on the base class.

```
    export class model2{
  constructor(public modelUser: string){
    console.log(modelUser);
  }
}
export class model1 extends model2{

  constructor(public modelUser: string){
    super(modelUser);
    console.log(this.modelUser)
  }
}
let y=new model2('model2');
let x=new model1('model1');
```